# Images of slideshow appear in codepen but not when I open the file on my browser?

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow, image-gallery

I copied a code from W3C to make a slideshow for my website. I was writing my code on codepen and the images were appearing. Then when I copied my code to my editor (Sublime)to add to my html file,the images don't appear. I tried copy the code again from the W3C thinking I left a part of the code and nothing appears. I had the images saved on my computer and tried to put them instead of the image address that I copied from the website I got them from and it still doesn't appear. I attached some images to help understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm new at coding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your code, not (only) images please. Read about [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Save your html file in parent directory of images(in your case it is pictures folder on your pc). I think that's why it's not showing the images.
or copy your images to the project folder.

Comment: I moved the images folder to the folder where I had the html files and the image appeared. Thank you so much! Now I can add images to my website.